# Why does my UIButton affect my UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm building a simple app in Swift, and the app contains a png image, a UISegmentedControl, and a UIButton. Selecting different controls on the UISegmentedControl resizes an image of a pizza. When I click on "Large" in the UISegmentedControl, and then I press a button on the interface called submitOrderDisplay, it shrinks the image from its large size to its small size. I know it has something to do with the setTitle method I am using at the very bottom of the code, but I don't understand why that causes the image to reset to its default small size. If I remove the setTitle method, the resizing does not occur after I click the UIButton. I don't want the image to change size after the button is pressed. How do I achieve that?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var sizeChoiceControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var submitOrderDisplay: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func sizeSelected() {

    if(sizeChoiceControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(sizeChoiceControl.selectedSegmentIndex)! == "Small"){
        myImageView.setHeight(height: 85)
        myImageView.setWidth(width: 85)
        myImageView.setX(x: 146)
        myImageView.setY(y: 63)
    }
    else if(sizeChoiceControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(sizeChoiceControl.selectedSegmentIndex)! == "Medium"){
        myImageView.setHeight(height: 100)
        myImageView.setWidth(width: 100)
        myImageView.setX(x: 139)
        myImageView.setY(y: 55)
    }
    else if(sizeChoiceControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(sizeChoiceControl.selectedSegmentIndex)! == "Large"){
        myImageView.setHeight(height: 115)
        myImageView.setWidth(width: 115)
        myImageView.setX(x: 131)
        myImageView.setY(y: 48)
    }
}

@IBAction func SubmitOrderClicked(sender: UIButton) { 

    submitOrderDisplay.setTitle("Update Order", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
}
```

Comment: Do you use autolayout and do you have constraints between the image view and the button (maybe "same width" or something)?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Yes I am using autolayout, that box is checked. In Referencing Outlets I see that the myImageView is connected to "Customize". Not sure what that means. But I don't see any other contraints between the image view and anything else.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I tried turning autolayout off and that fixed the problem, but Is that the only way to prevent the image resize? I've read that without using autolayout it will be hard for my app to support all screen resolutions, so I am nervous about turning it off.

Comment: When you use autolayout, you'll have to ensure that the constraints you define still hold while modifying the width and height of your controls. So you'll have to constraint the imageView to something like "centered" and not to e.g. a fixed distance to the borders. Unfortunately, this is often quite tricky, so it'll be hard to explain in a short comment. You'll have to play around and if you still got stuck, post your constraints and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Write the configuration of the button inside the viewDidLoad function:

```
submitOrderDisplay.setTitle("Update Order", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I understand that you want to put the title Update Order.

If you want to change the title when pressed, you must call it for another State of the button like:

```
submitOrderDisplay.setTitle("Update Order", forState: UIControlState.Highlihgted)
```

If you change the configuration of the button for different states when an event happens, that must be why the size is ressetting.